# Relate access token granted through Firebase Cloud Function to User instance

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

Since there is no way to implement a complete OAuth2 flow in Flutter web ([because of this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/oauth2/issues/88)), I'm using a cloud function as the callback listener. The process is initiated by the user in the web app and, instead of the web app listening for the callback, the redirect url is that of a cloud function that unpacks the token and stores it in Firestore.
What would be a good way to relate the request the auth server makes to my cloud function to the individual user which is registered in my app's database? In other words: how does the firebase cloud function know for which user in Firestore to store the access token?

My idea is to make another wrapper function that gets called from the web app when the user initiates the flow (receiving the user id as parameter) and have the function that receives the token from the external service also call this wrapper function, but this doesn't scale well (if you have multiple users at the same time, it could misplace each other's tokens).

Comment: "how does the firebase cloud function know for which user in Firestore to store the access token?" It doesn't. The ID token is passed (and validated) with each request.

Comment: I know it doesn't. The question is: "how do we make it know?"